# Android battery/usage stats

Tags: android, sdk, battery, usage-statistics

How can one access the battery and usage information, in general and on a per-app basis ?
On my S5 & S2 the information is displayed in the Settings/Battery menus but I can't find any reference on this in the Android SDK docs.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'formal' way of accessing per app battery usage. I know
some hacks, but they are messy and will probably not work on >= Android 4.4.

You can, however, use debug time tools that provide per-app data.
[ATT ARO](http://developer.att.com/application-resource-optimizer) is by far the best of them.

When it comes to global battery usage things gets better.

From any point within your code you can get the current battery level by:

```
int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
if (level == -1 || scale == -1) {
   return 40f; // or any other default
}
float batteryLevelPercent = level / (float)scale;
```

If you are interested in ongoing monitoring of battery state, you could register a 'battery changed' receiver:

```
void registerBatteryStateListener() {
    BroadcastReceiver batteryStateListener = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        int scale = -1;
        int level = -1;
        int voltage = -1;
        int temp = -1;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
            temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1);
            voltage = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);
            Log.e("BatteryStat", "level = " + level + ", scale = " + scale);
        }
    };
    IntentFilter changeFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(batteryStateListener, changeFilter);
}
```

And add relevant permission to manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"></uses-permission>
```

Note that ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED is a sticky intent. meaning it will basically run forever.